# MVC 4 Checkbox posted back twice - both null

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a simple enough requirement to post a boolean to and from a form in MVC 4. I am using Html.CheckBox rather than Html.CheckBoxFor because the boolean is nullable.

My code looks like this:

```
@Html.CheckBox("IsNonUk", Model.IsNonUk.GetValueOrDefault(false))
```

The HTML generated by this markup looks like this:

```
<input id="IsNonUk" name="IsNonUk" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="IsNonUk" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I understand the reasoning behind generating a hidden field, but the problem is that inspecting the post back with Fiddler reveals that the IsNonUk value is being posted back twice and the value of both of these form variables is null.

What am I doing wrong?

== Edit in response to comments

The controller action signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateSelfPay(CreateSelfPayViewModel viewModel)
```

The CreateSelfPayViewModel has a property:

```
public bool? IsNonUk { get; set; }
```

The property must be nullable for reasons I can't briefly explain. A drop down with true, false and unspecified is not possible within the design. I am quite happy for a null value to be rendered as unchcecked.

As I say, Fiddler reveals that the form variable is being posted back twice, both null.

M

Comment: Post your controller method your posting back to. It should have a parameter `bool IsNonUk` or a model which contains that property.

Comment: What gets posted if the box is ticked?

Comment: And if its nullable bool, you should be using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsNonUk)` which renders a dropdown with 3 values (True, False and Not Set), otherwise how would you ever select a `null` value

Comment: A checkbox has only 2 states whereas a nullable bool has 3 states. It makes no sense. You can't post back null unless you use javascript to disable both controls.

Comment: I don't want to post back null. I want to post back false in this case. I fully understand where you're coming from, but this nullable element is embedded into the code and it would be quite a lot of work to get it to function with a non-nullable bool. For my purposes, the bool would render as false if it's null.

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce your issue, unfortunately I'm not able to.  I can see that my view is rendered the same as yours and in fiddler I can see the form data (fiddler:webforms) has the value set correctly (false or true) as per my selection.  Maybe you could show the values from the webform in fiddler in your question.  Also, as others have pointed out, are you sure your View Model needs to be nullable, I can understand your domain model but not so clear on why for the view model, especially as you don't seem to be using the null value.

Comment: @user343159, What your claiming is not possible unless you have some javascript which is changing the values of the inputs to null. If the checkbox is checked, it will post back 2 values `True` and `False`. If the checkbox is unchecked it will post back one value `False`

Comment: because you have two elements with IsNonUk name attribute it is posted twice in your request , second you don't need the hidden field , i don't understand why you are using this ?

Comment: @vishalsharma, It is required. The hidden input is rendered by the `@Html.Checkbox()` method because unchecked checkboxes do not post back. The hidden input ensures a value is posted back and can be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`

Comment: @StephenMuecke , ok got that , but with having checkbox , i don't think he will ever receive null value , what you say ?

Comment: Ok, without sounding rude I think you're missing the point. I don't think that the view model parameter is nullable should make any difference. It would not explain why both parameters in Fiddler are empty. Or would it...